# Android studio get time from my timer, in order to get distance

Tags: android

i have created a timer, and it works well. And now i wanna use the timer, lets say, every 5 seconds, i will get the location of the user. And then i test if the method works or not. So i put `oxy++`(Field in MainActivity) in it, and see if it really runs in every 5secs. And then i got a problem.

```
public class MapsActivity extends BaseActivity /*implements LocationListener*/{

int oxy = 0;

private int isReset = 1;
private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private Button resetButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private GoogleMap mMap; 
private Button testbtn;
double x;
double y;
double j;
double k;
float dis;
TextView txt;
Location locationA;
Location locationB;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();


    textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);


    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);

            //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //Location locationA = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            //x = locationA.getLatitude();
            //y = locationA.getLongitude();

        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

        }
    });

    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textTimer.setText("0:00:00");
            timeSwap=0;
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;
        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        int test = (int) (finalTime%5000);
        if (test==0) {
            oxy++;
        }
        txt.setText("o = "+ test+ "  "+ oxy);
    }
};
```

Runnable updateTimerMethod is a loop, it runs for every millisecond.
So if i use seconds%5000, it runs when every 5s, but oxy keeps++ itself til the milliseconds have been added up to increase the seconds to 6.
Then i use finalTime which is in millisecond, to %5000. It doesn't work in every 5s, oxy+1 irregularly in the multiple of 5 when i re-run the program, lets say oxy+1 in 25s, 55s, 85s in the 1st time. Then i re-run it, oxy+1 in 45s, 65s, 105s. 
Can someone tell why it happened? Is there any way to solve this? As i wanna use this to get location in every 50s. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using method `Handler.postDelayed` is not a good idea for time sense stuff, since it is not accurate enough. Rather use [TimeAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeAnimator.html) (API11+, or NineOldAndroids for below).

Basic usage of TimeAnimator:

```
TimeAnimator anim = new TimeAnimator();
anim.setTimeListener(new TimeAnimator.TimeListener() {
    long time = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator timeAnimator, long t, long dt) {
        time += dt;
        if (time >= 5000) { // >= needed because this also might be not totally accurate...
            time -= 5000; // keep the remainder (if there is) to correct the accuracy of next loop

            // do stuff here (in every 5 seconds)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell more about how to use TimeAnimator??

Comment: So i should add this inside the code of startbutton? If so, where should i add txt.setText(oxy); , in order to check if it really runs in every 5s?